# C# LINQ Multiple GroupJoin using Lambda Syntax

Tags: c#, linq, left-join

I have 3 tables that I am trying to combine them together using left joins. In my application, all LINQ expressions are in query-chain format (lambda expressions).

I am trying to figure out how to accomplish this query using LINQ;

This is my SQL query;

```
select i.INVOICE_NUMBER, ic.CustomerName, o.BusinessUnit
from Invoices_Daily as i
left join intercompany as ic on i.customer_number = ic.customernumber
left join ordertypes as o on i.LINE_ORDERTYPE = o.OrderType
```

I have tried combining the `GroupJoin` as follows;

```
var commissions = data
    .GroupJoin(genericNameList,
        d => d.CUSTOMER_NUMBER,
        g => g.CustomerId,
        (d, g) => new { d, generic = g.FirstOrDefault() })
    .GroupJoin(intercompanies,
        dd => dd.d.CUSTOMER_NAME,
        i => i.CustomerId,
        (d, i) => new { data = d.d, intercompanies = i.FirstOrDefault() })
    .Select(_ => new MainGridViewModel
    {
        INVOICE_DATE = _.d.INVOICE_DATE,
        EndCustomer = _.generic == null ? _.d.CUSTOMER_NAME : _.generic.EndCustomer ?? _.d.CUSTOMER_NAME,
        LINE_ORDERTYPE = _.i.OrderType
    })
    .ToList();
```

However I am having a syntax error that is written below;

> Error CS0411  The type arguments for method 'Enumerable.GroupJoin(IEnumerable, IEnumerable, Func, Func, Func, TResult>)' cannot be inferred from the usage. Try specifying the type arguments explicitly.

Comment: Seems like the keys (`CUSTOMER_NAME` and `CustomerId`) have different types. 

Also note that `(d, i) => new { data = d.d, intercompanies = i.FirstOrDefault() })` would be translated to something like `outer apply (select top 1 ...)` instead of `left join`.

Comment: @2kay `CUSTOMER_NAME` and `CustomerId` are both `string` type. When I use `GroupJoin` with the `FirstOrDefault` it always brings me the same results as I do left join on SQL side. I never encountered any issues yet. Its my first time tying to combine multiple tables...

Comment: @0014 which line is it happening at the first GroupJoin or the Second?

Comment: @johnny5 The problem happens on the second `GroupJoin`. In fact the intellisense does not give any results when I type `i => i.` on the second `GroupJoin` where I am expecting the IDE to bring all the columns for `intercompanies`.

Comment: See my new answer you're using the wrong variable name

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I wrote a test sample as per request showing the proper syntax, this should all be working.

```
public class Data
{
    public string CUSTOMER_NUMBER { get; set; }
    public string CUSTOMER_NAME { get; set; }
}

public class NameList
{
    public string CustomerId { get; set; }

}

public class InterCompanies
{
    public string CustomerId { get; set; }
}

public class Test
{
    public void TMP()
    {
        var data = new List<Data>();
        var genericNameList = new List<NameList>();
        var intercompanies = new List<InterCompanies>();

        var commissions = data
            .GroupJoin(genericNameList,
                d => d.CUSTOMER_NUMBER,
                g => g.CustomerId,
                (d, g) => new { d, generic = g.FirstOrDefault() })
            .GroupJoin(intercompanies,
                dd => dd.d.CUSTOMER_NAME,
                i => i.CustomerId,
                (d, i) => new { data = d.d, intercompanies = i.FirstOrDefault() })
            .ToList();
    }
}
```

My Original Thought was that you CUSTOMER_NUMBER, and CUSTOMER_NAME is wrong because why do you have 2 fields in the same class with the same value. But since you assured me they're correct, Maybe you're swapping the order of the fields expected on the data in the join, It's hard to tell without seeing your data models.

Perhaps your second join should look like so:

```
.GroupJoin(intercompanies,
            dd => dd.d.CUSTOMER_NUMBER,
            i => i.CUSTOMER_NAME,
```

Comment: I wish this was the answer however its not :( both are string type columns anyway. It did not make any difference. If you have a project somewhere open you can see that combining two `GroupJoin`s gives a syntax error.

Comment: I just wrote this manually and it worked fine, should me the Class definition for, genericNameList, and intercompanies

Comment: Can you please provide the query that works fine ? The classes does not matter I would like to see how you wrote the query with two `GroupJoin`s that works without any syntax error. Please add it to your solution if possible.

Comment: 0014 Okay I'll post in a second

Comment: I still think It's a variable naming issue, it seems wierd that there are different named field which both join on customerId,  It's hard to tell since I don't know what  genericNameList or interCompanies are.

Comment: @0014,  let me know if you have any other issues, If you post the data models I'll be able to tell what's wrong, if this fixes your issue please mark as resolve

Comment: Johnny thanks a lot, the problem was all my fault that I left `intercompanies` in an `List<IQueryable>()` state. I looks like I forgot to add `ToList()` at the end while creating `intercompanies`. I realized it while tying to implement your code. Thanks for making me realize it :)

Comment: Thanks I'm always happy to help